# Ubuntu Budgie 18.04: Is there a way to customize date format?

Tags: 18.04, budgie

I've set up my Budgie panel to show the current date.
However I would like to change date format. For example, it'd be nice to see the same as the following command shows:

```
date '+%d %b'
```

Is there a way to achive that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Options to set the date format

#### 1. Calendar applet

The default installed Clock applet does not have an option to set a custom date format. Not from GUI (Budgie Settings), not from dconf.

***However***, you can install the **Calendar Applet**, which does offer the option. To install:

1. Choose from the main menu <kbd>Budgie Applets</kbd>, and install the Calendar Applet
2. Log out and back in
3. Open Budgie Settings from the main menu, add the applet to the panel (click the + -> add)

Then, in the applet's settings, tick "Custom date" and set your string format:

[image]

..and here we are:

[image]

#### 2. ShowTime applet (on the desktop)

Not literally the question, but in the latest version of the ShowTime applet (time on the desktop) you can also set a custom date format.

To change the format from:

[image]

into:

[image]

Simply run:

```
gsettings set org.ubuntubudgie.plugins.budgie-showtime dateformat '%d %b'
```

and subsequently restart the applet or log out/in. To revert, run:

```
gsettings set org.ubuntubudgie.plugins.budgie-showtime dateformat ''
```

#### N.B.

For the latest version to be available, you need to enable Backports repository from Budgie Welcome (in Recommendations)

Comment: Manual page for the format string: `man strftime`